# Symbols in GNU Assembly

Tags: linux, gnu

I'm wondering what is the difference of these variables in GNU assembly. Thanks!

```
$variable_name 
variable_name
(variable_name)
```

Comment: and I don't know which one them will hold the address of the variable

Answer (score 0):

[`$`, `.` and `_` are part of the symbol's name](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Intro.html#Symbol-Intro), so `a` and `$a` are just two different symbols. The `$` character doesn't have any special meaning (like in the shell).

So the first two are simply different symbols.

The parenthesis are used for mathematical operations; they are not part of the symbol name, so `a` and `(a)` are equivalent while `(a*b)+1` and `a*(b+1)` are not.

Comment: Thanks. But can you tell me what would be the symbol for an address in gnu assembly?

Comment: That depends on the type of symbol. When the symbol is a label (`a:`), then the value is the address. If it's a variable or constant, then there is no address.

Comment: But how will I do a pass-by-reference function? In nasm i would push the address into the stack, and then access the variable in the main function through the address passed..

Comment: It's exactly the same in GNU as.